# Virtual machine isn't recognizing file changes when altered on host machine unless "ls -l" is triggered

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, mount, fstab

I am seeing a weird issue on a virtual machine running on a server of mine. I set up a little test scenario below that illustrates the symptoms of what I am experiencing and I can't figure out what else to look at.

So I have the following criteria

1. Virtiofs Mode for "/mnt/user/Backup/Logs/"(host) => "logs"(virtual machine debian)
2. fstab entry of "logs /mnt/logs virtiofs ro,relatime,sync 0 0"
3. Full rwe on the test file

I executed the commands back and forth from left to right.

1. root "ls -l" to display the current directory on unraid os
2. alexander "ls -l" to display current directory on the virtual machine
3. root "cat testfile" to display the content of the file on unraid
4. alexander "cat testfile" to display the content of the file on the virtual machine
5. root "sudo nano testfile" and append a string in nano
6. root "cat testfile" to display the new content after nano modify
7. alexander "cat testfile" still has the old content of the file
8. alexander "ls -l" which relists the directory and refreshes some cache
9. alexander "cat testfile" now has the new content from unraid drive.

[image: Example commands]

I am not exactly sure what is happening as it seems like the virtual machine has an older copy of the file and only when I do a "ls -l" (or something equivalent where it refreshes it) does the file correctly update.

This whole thing stemmed from me trying to forward a log file using filebeat only to find out that the log was being written to from the host machine but the virtual machine never actually noticed the file changing until a "ls -l" was ran in the directory of that log file.